# sorting excel Macro get stuck in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a VBA which works fine (Takes time to execute) in my excel 365 but does not work in excel 2016

I am importing excel as SHEET (2) and sorting first and second sheet respective columns and copying second sheet to first after last used column.

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("SHEET").Select
    Range("C1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SHEET").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SHEET").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range _
        ("C1:C50000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SHEET").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Sheets("SHEET (2)").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SHEET (2)").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SHEET (2)").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:= _
        Range("A1:A50000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption _
        :=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SHEET (2)").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("SHEET").Select

 Sheets("SHEET (2)").Select ' origin sheet
 Range("A1").Select
 Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
 X = Selection.Columns.count ' get number of columns

       Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("SHEET").Select  ' destination sheet
        Range("AH1").Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
```

I have two problems

1. code get stuck with runtime error 438 at line of in excel 2016

```
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SHEET").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range _
        ("C1:C50000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
```

2. If I have more than 10000 rows its runs very slowly.

can any one guide me with this please?

Comment: Is it slow when you apply the filters manually?

Comment: no i think copy of sheet, importing and copy of columns is slow, may be I should copy column by column